# What happens if one user approves an edit and another rejects it?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review

With the recent change that suggested edits must reviewed twice on all sites (except SO), I had a question:

What happens if one user (me, for example) rejects an edit and another user (Jon Skeet, for example) chooses to approve it? Is it rejected or approved?

*This is banning the circumstance in which one of the users is a moderator (I believe the moderator's decision overrides the other).*

Comment: Then a third vote is required. (And the post author's vote is also binding, like a moderator vote.)

Comment: I thought it was something simple, but I've never had this happen myself.

Comment: Whatever you do, stop, drop and roll....it can't be good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On sites that are not Stack Overflow, two users are required to reject/accept a suggested edit. Until there aren't two users who give the same response, the suggested edit will be kept in the review queue.

This is what happened for this [suggested edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9546), which was first rejected from a user, and then approved from two users.

[image: screenshot]

On Stack Overflow, where three users are required for a suggested edit to be accepted/rejected, you can have situations like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/937216).

[image: screenshot]

Also in this case, the suggested edit is still shown in the review page until three users don't select the same response.

As [Daniel Fischer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/177145/daniel-fischer) said, the vote of the post's author, as well as a moderator's vote are binding. That happens even when there aren't votes from other reviewers: A moderator, or the post's author can approve a suggested edit alone.

Comment: Also keep in mind the possibility of Improve, which pretty much overrides other reviewers decisions.